# How to do regex for Iban internationally

Tags: apex, regular-expressions, method, boolean

I found a regex example for international iban numbers but the is returning false. What am I doing wrong.

Apex

```
public static Boolean validateIban(String iban) {
        Boolean res = true;
        String ibanRegex = '^([A-Z]{2}[ '+'\\'+'-]?[0-9]{2})(?=(?:[ '+'\\'+'-]?[A-Z0-9]){9,30}$)((?:[ '+'\\'+'-]?[A-Z0-9]{3,5}){2,7})([ '+'\\'+'-]?[A-Z0-9]{1,3})?$'; 
        Pattern MyPattern = Pattern.compile(ibanRegex);
        if(iban!=null){
        Matcher MyMatcher = MyPattern.matcher(iban);
        if (!MyMatcher.matches()) 
            res = false;
        }
        return res; 
    }
```

Tested with: 'NL50RABO9737375777'

Comment: where did you find the example?

Comment: @KrisGoncalves  https://snipplr.com/view/15322/iban-regex-all-ibans/

Comment: Just a minor comment but right now if you call validateIban(null) then it returns true even though it isn't a valid iban.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Please check out this code.You forgot to put braces

```
public static Boolean validateIbanNumber(String iban) {

    Boolean res = true;
    String ibanRegex = '^([A-Z]{2}[ '+'\\'+'-]?[0-9]{2})(?=(?:[ '+'\\'+'-]?[A-Z0-9]){9,30}$)((?:[ '+'\\'+'-]?[A-Z0-9]{3,5}){2,7})([ '+'\\'+'-]?[A-Z0-9]{1,3})?$'; 
    Pattern MyPattern = Pattern.compile(ibanRegex);
    if(iban!=null){
        Matcher MyMatcher = MyPattern.matcher(iban);
        if (!MyMatcher.matches()) 
        {

            res = false;
        }

    } 
    return res; 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, should have seen that.